# WebView not allowing javascript with setJavaScriptEnabled true

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

So i am trying to incorporate a web view into my activity. The webview does not seem to be allowing Javascript even though i have setjavascriptenabled to true.

The url being loaded is http://www.lialpa.org/CM3/app.html right now it just contains a twitter list timeline. Yes i know i could do that with the twitter api but i plan to add other php generated content to that page and that way everything can be loaded together.

If i just navigate to http://www.lialpa.org/CM3/app.html the widget is working fine. In the webview it does not work. When i click the header link it takes me to another twitter page which tells me javascript is not enabled which is what makes me suspect javascript not being allowed is the problem.

My the code is below

```
WebView main_webView = new WebView(this);
    main_webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
    main_webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
    main_webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
    main_webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
    main_webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
    main_webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    main_webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    main_webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

    if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
        main_webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
    }



   // WebView main_webView;
    main_webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    main_webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    main_webView.loadUrl("http://www.lialpa.org/CM3/app.html");
    //end of webview setup




private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me :

```
webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEYS.WEBADRS));
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {...
```